# SELECT where an id is not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, I have a table structure where a student can take a test.

Structure is like this:

http://www.dropmocks.com/mBj9YX

```
SELECT s.name AS studentName, 
t.name AS testName,
MAX(sc.percentile) 
AS percentile,
    (CASE WHEN  MAX(sc.percentile) > 70 THEN 'passed' 
     WHEN MAX(sc.percentile) <70 THEN 'fail'
     WHEN  MAX(sc.percentile) IS NULL THEN 'not taken' END) AS status
FROM Score sc
```

the part that does not do want I want is here:

```
WHEN  MAX(sc.percentile) IS NULL THEN 'not taken' END
```

If a student does NOT take a test, the test ID will not be in the score table. I can't figure out a query that would add 'not taken' to the status column if they have not taken a test. Help? The first two work, but if there is a test ID in the test table and a student has not taken that test, then the test ID for that student will not show up in the score table. I am trying to find a way to detect that.

Comment: what do you really want?

Comment: A way to a detect the tests that a student has not taken.

Comment: Then you don't select directly from the table with the scores. Rather, do something like FROM STUDENT S JOIN TEST T ON ... LEFT JOIN SCORE SC ON ... WHERE SC.PrimaryKey IS NULL (alternatively, put the SC.PrimaryKey IS NULL in your CASE statement.

Comment: Warning: you are going to miss 70%, 70 is neither greater nor less than 70 ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using IS_MEMBER NULL instead of IS NULL? The IS_MEMBER function has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve (check if someone's in a role group). This sometimes happens because when you pressed space typing the query mssms added a IS_MEMBER. It happened to me in the past. Try changing

```
WHEN  MAX(sc.percentile) IS_MEMBER NULL THEN 'not taken'
```

to

```
WHEN  MAX(sc.percentile) IS NULL THEN 'not taken'
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant the second one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I never got to test, but tries so

```
SELECT
    sc.name AS studentName, 
    t.name AS testName,
    MAX(sc.percentile) AS percentile,
    (CASE
        WHEN MAX(sc.percentile) > 70 THEN 'passed'
        WHEN MAX(sc.percentile) < 70 THEN 'fail'
        WHEN sc.testID IS NULL THEN 'not taken'
        -- /*OR...*/ WHEN MAX(sc.percentile) IS NULL THEN 'not taken'
    END) AS status
FROM Score sc
FULL OUTER JOIN Test t ON t.testID = sc.testID
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly work. I have three students in the table and it doesn't do what I though it did.

Comment: Please, send me the script of creation and the insert script of tables.

Answer (score 0):

CASE var WHEN NULL THEN … will never succeed.

Use this:

CASE WHEN MAX(sc.percentile) IS NULL THEN 'not taken' ELSE '123' END

or just this:

COALESCE(MAX(sc.percentile), 'not taken')